Twilio POST request showing GET error: 405 Method Not Allowed
The issue is when Twilio sends a POST request to the /incoming-call endpoint, my server is returning a 405 Method Not Allowed error. The error log also shows that the server is attempting to handle the request as a GET request instead of a POST request.
Why is my server treating Twilio's POST request as a GET request, and how do I resolve the 405 Method Not Allowed error?
Is there any additional configuration required on Twilio or Uvicorn to properly handle POST requests?
My development environment:
Server: Uvicorn with FastAPI
Twilio Webhook Endpoint: /incoming-call
Language: Python 3.9
Framework: FastAPI
Hosting: Local environment or cloud server

Verified the Twilio Webhook Configuration:
I double-checked that the webhook URL configured in Twilio is correct (/incoming-call endpoint).
Tested the Endpoint Locally:
I sent a POST request manually to the /incoming-call endpoint using Postman, and the server responded correctly with a 200 OK.
Checked Server Code:
I ensured that my FastAPI route is configured to handle only POST requests, as shown below:
@app.post("/incoming-call")
async def incoming_call(request: dict):
    return Response("Call received", status_code=200)

Reviewed Server Logs:
I noticed in the logs that the server is treating the request as a GET request instead of a POST request:
INFO: 172.31.196.73:48386 - "GET /incoming-call HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed

What was I expecting?
I expected the server to successfully process the POST request sent by Twilio to the /incoming-call endpoint and return a 200 OK status. Instead, the server is returning a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

I think the problem is in Twilio's config.
Can you share that config (the part related to /incoming-call webhook)?
